# Using gdalwarp with c# bindings?

Tags: gdal, c#, gdalwarp

I want to change projections for images using gdal bindings for c#. Gdal_translate seems like just renaming of projection (using a_srs parameter), but not reprojecting, so I used gdalwarp with s_srs parameter for that task.
It's pretty clear what to pass to the `Gdal.wrapper_GDALTranslate` function: path to the destination file, dataset of the input file and some minor stuff. It also has more or less clear [documentation](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). But for gdalwarp there are 3 kinds of different methods:

```
Gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(string dest, int object_list_count, 
SWIGTYPE_p_p_GDALDatasetShadow poObjects,
GDALWarpAppOptions warpAppOptions, Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate callback,
string callback_data); //returns Dataset

Gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestDS(Dataset dstDS, int object_list_count,
SWIGTYPE_p_p_GDALDatasetShadow poObjects, GDALWarpAppOptions warpAppOptions,
Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate callback, string callback_data); //returns int

Gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(Dataset src_ds, string src_wkt, string dst_wkt, 
ResampleAlg eResampleAlg, double maxerror); //returns Dataset
```

It's absolutely not clear what these functions do and how they do it. Docs on [gdalwarp page](https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) don't have any of these. I also don't understand the parameters: there is no input file or dataset parameter, only destination ones; the `SWIGTYPE_p_p_GDALDatasetShadow` class, which also doesn't have [docs](https://www.gdal.org/gdal__utils_8h.html) (there are not a single word about "shadow" either).

Summarizing, I'd like to hear some explanations about how this funcs work and how to make them work as binary gdalwarp.exe does.

Answer (score 5):

Using [How to use wrapper_GDALWarpDestName in C#](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-February/046046.html), I managed to write working method, that works like console GdalWarp does.

```
public static bool GdalWarp(string inputFile, string outputFile, string[] options, OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate callback)
{
    using (Dataset inputDataset = Gdal.Open(inputFile, Access.GA_ReadOnly))
    {
        IntPtr[] ptr = {Dataset.getCPtr(inputDataset).Handle};
        GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(ptr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Dataset result = null;
        try
        {
            SWIGTYPE_p_p_GDALDatasetShadow dss = new SWIGTYPE_p_p_GDALDatasetShadow(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), false, null);
            result = Gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(outputFile, 1, dss, new GDALWarpAppOptions(options), callback, null);
        }
        catch (Exception) { return false; }
        finally
        {
            gcHandle.Free();
            result.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what your `GDALProgressFuncDelegate` looks like

Comment: `result.Dispose();` should be `result?.Dispose();`