Access Violation following rasterdataset.Close() after GdalWarp, GDAL C# bindings
I have the following C# code to mosaic multiple rasters using GDAL C# bindings and GdalWarp method:
       try
       {
            Gdal.AllRegister();

            // Open all the raster files in read-only mode
            var datasets = new Dataset[_filesToMerge.Count];
      
            for (int i = 0; i < _filesToMerge.Count; i++)
                datasets[i] = Gdal.Open(_filesToMerge[i], Access.GA_ReadOnly);

            // Set the warp options for the merge
            var warpOptions = new string[] {};
            var progressDelegate = new Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate(Progress);

            // Perform the merge using GDAL
            // Gdal.Warp(_outputFileName, datasets, new GDALWarpAppOptions(warpOptions), new Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate(Progress), "");
            var options = new GDALWarpAppOptions(warpOptions);
            
            var result = Gdal.Warp(_outputFileName, datasets, options, null, "warp");

            for (int i = 0; i < datasets.Length; i++)
                datasets[i].Close();

            warpOptions = null;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        {
            return false;
        }

The code works well and creates the raster as expected.
The problem starts right after a few seconds (sometimes 10), and while the app running, the following exception is thrown.
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

The problem occurs whenever i attempt to close the datasets after gdalwarp method is completed. If I dont close the datasets, no exception occurs but in that case, the files remain open till the app closes down.
I am sure that there is something remaining alive during the gdalwarp method call and when i try to close the datasets, it breaks remaining stuff related to the gdalwrap.
I am using GDAL 3.8.5 from nuget. App is windows forms using .net 4.8 and build in x64.
Is there any suggestion to propoerly close datasets after gdalwarp call while using C# bindings of GDAL ?

In the Python datasets I can see that dataset is set to None and gdal.Unlink is used https://github.com/rouault/gdal/blob/rfc_86/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp.py#L1228. Maybe that can give you some hint for C#.

The only option that i succeed is to set datasets to null, call Gdal.Unlink and wait GC to collect null variables. this way no Access Violation occurs and files remain closed.

There's a related post that uses a different overload, in that post the warping is done in a function, the datasets are not implicitly closed but handled by the GC when the function ends and the dataset(s) go out of scope, it might be worth a try, read more https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297831/using-gdalwarp-with-c-bindings the pinning of the GC in that thread makes me think that the warp is happening on a different thread and you're closing the datasets while warp is still using them, i.e. a race conditon.
